# Warning message when summing from a elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, summation

Why does adding two elements from a list as follows:

```
test = {1, 2};
NSum[test[[n]], {n, 1, 2}]
```

lead to the warning "The expression n cannot be used as a part specification."? It does produce the correct answer but I don't know how to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Any reason you want to use `NSum` for this instead of `Total`?

Comment: I'm wanting to sum only certain elements of a much bigger list. The example above is merely a simple demonstration of the error I was getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the reason for the warning is because:

> NSum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.

> NSum has attribute HoldAll, and effectively uses Block to localize variables.

So under the hood it is doing something like

```
Clear[n]
{1, 2}[[n]] (* triggers your error *)

n = 1;
{1, 2}[[n]] (* produces your answer *)
```

---

To get rid of the warning does this work for you?

```
test = {1, 2};
NSum[Indexed[test, n], {n, 1, 2}] (*3.*)
```

Comment: PS: the notes on `NSum` are from the documentation

Comment: Thanks. That did indeed remove the error.